# How do I pass my functions through two components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, debugging

So I have a state :

```
toggleWatched:false
```

These are the four functions in App.js file that will be passed through to the MovieCard component :

```
    watchedMovie= () => {
    console.log("WATCHED MOOPIE");
}

notWatchedMovie = () => {
    console.log("HAVENT WATCHED MOOPIE");

}


handleChange= () => {
    this.setState({toggleWatched:!this.state.toggleWatched})
}

Toggling = () => {
    this.state.toggleWatched ? this.watchedMovie : this.notWatchedMovie;
}
```

Before passing to the MovieCard it has to be passed through the favorites component :

```
                              <Favorites
                                {...props}
                                handleChange={this.handleChange}
                                Toggling={this.Toggling}
                                toggleWatched={this.state.toggleWatched}
                            />
```

Then in favorites.js's render :

```
 const {
        Toggling,
        handleChange,
        toggleWatched,
    } = this.props;
```

Then it is passed to the movie card which is a constant component :

```
                            <MovieCard
                                handleChange={handleChange}
                                Toggling={Toggling}
                                toggleWatched={toggleWatched}

                            />
```

In the movie card it is used like :

```
const MovieCard = ({ handleChange,Toggling,})
```

I made a button in MovieCard which handles it :

```
               <button style={{fontSize:"14px"}} onClick={handleChange}>
           {
               Toggling
           }
            </button>
```

When I press the button, there's no error but nothing is consoled as well. I don't know what the error is. Can someone help me fix this?

Comment: `MovieCard` and `Favorites` are both class component or functional component?

Comment: App and Favorites are both class and MovieCard is a functional/stateless component

Answer (score 1):

I think I know the problem. Your function `Toggling` is not being invoked. A function will not be invoked by itself, you are only passing `handleChange` to the button `onClick` at `MovieCard` and so only function `handleChange` being invoked. And what it does is only `setState` for `toggleWatched`.

From your case, your `handleChange` function should be as following

```
handleChange= () => {
  this.setState({toggleWatched:!this.state.toggleWatched}, () => this.Toggling())
}
```

We are passing `this.Toggling()` as a second parameter of `setState` because `this.setState` is asynchronous

Comment: How would you invoke the toggling function?

Comment: @rockwire: You can make your `handleChange` function to invoke `this.Toggling` right after `setState`. I've updated my solution

Comment: @rockwire: Please do update me as I wish to know if it works for your case, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is the way you use function. Missing ()

```
Toggling = () => {
    this.state.toggleWatched ? this.watchedMovie() : this.notWatchedMovie();
}
```

And button in MovieCard must be use

```
<button style={{fontSize:"14px"}} onClick={handleChange}>
            <Toggling />
</button>
```

Or

```
<button style={{fontSize:"14px"}} onClick={handleChange}>
            {Toggling()}
</button>
```

Update:
The button must have content, so I suggest U change MovieCard like that

```
<div>
   <button style={{fontSize:"14px"}} onClick={handleChange}>
        Click
   </button>
   <Toggling />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, this will not be a good approach if you call your function like

```
<button style={{fontSize:"14px"}} onClick={handleChange}>
    {
        Toggling()
    }
</button>
```

What should be done is, you should call Toggling after the call of `handleChange`. Something like:

```
watchedMovie= () => {
    console.log("WATCHED MOOPIE");
}

notWatchedMovie = () => {
    console.log("HAVENT WATCHED MOOPIE");

}


handleChange= () => {
    this.setState({toggleWatched:!this.state.toggleWatched}, this.Toggling);
}

Toggling = () => {
    this.state.toggleWatched ? this.watchedMovie() : this.notWatchedMovie();
}
```